# Checking Run Time / Compile Time in a widget?

Tags: android

I have a custom widget and want to check in it: whether we are in compile time or run time?
My widget does some process in run time, but i want to show a simple text in XML layout preview in compile time.
Is there any way for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show something while the apps load, use a launch screen. you cannot show text at that time as far as I know.

Comment: No, I want to show a text in design time. Like in VB6 ActiveX controls that we had a command for checking design time / run time : "Ambient.UserMode"